# Update variable retrieved form the database after submitting

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have 2 classes `Games` and `Fouls`, there are lot of fouls in a game. The user sends a parameter with the game `id` to find the `game` he want and after that the `currentGame` variable is created.Its type is `Game`. I have a `datatable` which prints the fouls in the current game

The `setCurentGame` setter is called form the body of the page `onload`.

so far everything works okay, but when I add a new `foul`, is not added to the datatable, my assumption is that the game was already retrieved (because current game was created before)  so the new foul is in the database and not in the Game currentGame.

Is there any way that i can update the currentGame every time a foul i added?

I have tried refreshing the page and even to call the seeter again after creating the foul but nothing worked

The `datatable` looks like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{gameController.currentGame.foulCollection}" var="item">

                    <f:facet name="{exporters}">

                    </f:facet>
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>

                    <p:column width="32" sortBy="#{item.id}" filterBy="#{item.id}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFoulTitle_id}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column sortBy="#{item.quarter}" filterBy="#{item.quarter}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFoulTitle_quarter}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.quarter}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column sortBy="#{item.foultime}" filterBy="#{item.foultime}">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListFoulTitle_foultime}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.foultime}"/>
                    </p:column>





                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:commandButton id="createButton" icon="ui-icon-plus"   value="#{bundle.Create}" actionListener="#{foulController.prepareCreate}" update=":FoulCreateForm" oncomplete="PF('FoulCreateDialog').show()"/>

                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>
```

GameController bean:

```
package onisiforos.fouls.classes;

import onisiforos.fouls.db.Game;
import onisiforos.fouls.classes.util.JsfUtil;
import onisiforos.fouls.classes.util.JsfUtil.PersistAction;
import onisiforos.fouls.bean.GameFacade;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.EJBException;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@Named("gameController")
@SessionScoped
public class GameController implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private onisiforos.fouls.bean.GameFacade ejbFacade;
    private List<Game> items = null;
    private Game selected;
    private Game currentGame;

    public Game getCurrentGame() {
        return currentGame;
    }



    public void setCurrentGame() {
        int gid =
        Integer.parseInt(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("gameid"));
        Game cg = getGame(gid);
        this.currentGame = cg;
    }




    public GameController() {
    }

    public Game getSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(Game selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    protected void setEmbeddableKeys() {
    }

    protected void initializeEmbeddableKey() {
    }

    private GameFacade getFacade() {
        return ejbFacade;
    }

    public Game prepareCreate() {
        selected = new Game();
        initializeEmbeddableKey();
        return selected;
    }



        public void create() {
            setCurrentGame()
            persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("GameCreated"));
            updateCurrentGame();
            if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
                items = null;    
            }
        }

    public void update() {
        persist(PersistAction.UPDATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("GameUpdated"));
    }

    public void destroy() {
        persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("GameDeleted"));
        if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
            selected = null; // Remove selection
            items = null;    
        }
    }

    public List<Game> getGames() {
        if (items == null) {
            items = getFacade().findAll();
        }
        return items;
    }

    private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
        if (selected != null) {
            setEmbeddableKeys();
            try {
                if (persistAction != PersistAction.DELETE) {
                    getFacade().edit(selected);
                } else {
                    getFacade().remove(selected);
                }
                JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);
            } catch (EJBException ex) {
                String msg = "";
                Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
                if (cause != null) {
                    msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
                }
                if (msg.length() > 0) {
                    JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
                } else {
                    JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Game getGame(java.lang.Integer id) {
        return getFacade().find(id);
    }

    public List<Game> getItemsAvailableSelectMany() {
        return getFacade().findAll();
    }

    public List<Game> getItemsAvailableSelectOne() {
        return getFacade().findAll();
    }

    @FacesConverter(forClass = Game.class)
    public static class GameControllerConverter implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, String value) {
            if (value == null || value.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            GameController controller = (GameController) facesContext.getApplication().getELResolver().
                    getValue(facesContext.getELContext(), null, "gameController");
            return controller.getGame(getKey(value));
        }

        java.lang.Integer getKey(String value) {
            java.lang.Integer key;
            key = Integer.valueOf(value);
            return key;
        }

        String getStringKey(java.lang.Integer value) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(value);
            return sb.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent component, Object object) {
            if (object == null) {
                return null;
            }
            if (object instanceof Game) {
                Game o = (Game) object;
                return getStringKey(o.getId());
            } else {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "object {0} is of type {1}; expected type: {2}", new Object[]{object, object.getClass().getName(), Game.class.getName()});
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is your managed bean Session scoped or request scoped? i think the setter method is not proper for retrieving currentGame from database, you can use @PostConstruct method to do this(if your bean is request scoped).

Comment: Thank for the response. My bean its SessionScoped.  @Mojtaba Safaeian

Comment: please add your complete xhtml and beans code

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **setCurrentGame** method will not be called, you can manually call it in your **create()** method to update the current game object from the database after the foul is created.

Comment: I have already tried this. setCurrentGame is called but still the values in it are not updated

Comment: By the way i forgot to mention that when i update a foul, the foul is updated in the datatable too, but when creating or deleting one no update happens in the datatable. but all three operations work fine with the database.

Comment: Are you sure setCurrentGame is called after updating the database?

Comment: i think so, i have updated the create() method in the question. the foul is added to the database, i guess setcurrentGame must be called

Comment: Why don't you debug  your code to see what's happening?